# How to get return value of typescript async function in time

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm creating a Firebase Cloud Function that relies upon some data about whether or not certain keys exist in the realtime database, but it's not getting properly returned.

I've tried wrapping the function being called through the async/await keywords or by directly constructing a Promise, but it keeps either returning undefined or Promise {  }

```
async function checkMatchExists(baseUser: string, friend:string){
  return await admin.database().ref('pairs/').child(baseUser).once("value", 
  snapshot => {
      return snapshot.exists();
  });
}
```

in main function:

```
let matchExists;

if(checkMatchExists(userId, eachUserId)){
   console.log("match exists in db!")
   matchExists = true;
} else {
   matchExists = false
   console.log("match not here yet");
}

if(distance <= 0.0092 && !(userId === eachUserId) && !matchExists){
             console.log("Match exists:");
             console.log(matchExists);
}
```

I've also tried directly plugging `checkMatchExists(userId, eachUserId)` directly into the if statement but to no avail. The following just produces undefined as well:

```
(async () => {
      console.log(checkMatchExists(eachUserId, userId));
 })().then(result => {
      console.log(result);
 }).catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
 });
```

Everything I've tried results in `undefined` or `Promise { <pending> }` but I need the actual result. The console does return `"match exists in db!"` but thats just because if evaluated Promise {  } as true. How do I wait for the promise to resolve?

EDIT: It turns out I'll need to make an `await` call within another `await` method. Is this possible in TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async functions always return a promise.  Your code looks like it's assuming that the return value is always a boolean.  Since async functions always return a promise, you should be using `await` or using then/catch to determine what happened with the promise.

```
const exists = await checkMatchExists(userId, eachUserId)
```

Comment: I get `"await" expression is only allowed in async functions`. The header of my main function is `exports.geolocationEventDetector = functions.database
    .ref("/locations/{userId}/l").onUpdate(async (change, context) => { /*code here*/ });` Do you know a workaround?

Comment: I should also add that I tried the then/catch method and the same undefined return has occurred:                                                                                         
           `const userExists = checkMatchExists(userId, eachUserId).then(result => {
                console.log(result);
              }).catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
              });`

Comment: You must not be showing all the code here. That error message doesn't lie.

Comment: Turns out I was doing this inside of another await function: `await admin.database()
          .ref("locations").orderByChild('uid').once('value', userList =>{
            let sentToUser;
            userList.forEach(function(child){ /*where all the troubles have been occurring*/}) }`                                                                                                                         What you suggested requires that I do an await statement within another await statement. Is that possible or is there a workaround?